# How to configure a plugin with custom sourceSet extension in Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I could use a helping hand converting victor trellos simple sourceSet extension to Kotlin DSL, I seem a bit lost.

Victor Trello has an extension on SourceSet named `svg`

```
    project.extensions.create('victor', VictorPluginExtension)
    // Add 'svg' as a source set extension
    project.android.sourceSets.all { sourceSet ->
        SourceDirectorySet sds = project.objects.sourceDirectorySet(sourceSet.name, "${sourceSet.name} svgs")
        sourceSet.extensions.add('svg', sds)
    }
```

This is how it is configured in Groovy:

```
// build.gradle:
android {
    // Variant 1 with individual setup
    sourceSets {
        main {
            svg.srcDir 'src/main/svg'
        }
    }
    // Variant 2 handling all at once
    sourceSets.all { sourceSet ->
        svg.srcDir "src/${sourceSet.name}/svg"
    }
}
// Plugin configuration of class com.trello.victor.VictorPluginExtension
victor {
    svgDpi = 72
    generateVectorDrawables = true
}
```

What would this look like in Kotlin DSL?

Here's the [Victor Trello Gradle Plugin source](https://github.com/trello/victor/blob/master/victor/src/main/groovy/com/trello/victor/VictorPlugin.groovy)

I notice that the Victor plugin extends SourceSet, and project.sourceSet has type SourceSet (from gradle) which contains an extensions, whereas AndroidSourceSet does not contain the .extensions. Also I can seem to get a gradle SourceSet from the AndroidSourceSet

---

This might be the right way to do the plugin configuration, though I cannot test it without the srcDir (I'll remove this from the question if its wrong, to avoid confusion for future readers).

```
// build.gradle.kts:
configure<com.trello.victor.VictorPluginExtension> {
    svgDpi = 72
    generateVectorDrawables = true
}
```

Comment: Have you found the solution? I'm looking for Kotlin DSL of this part: `afterEvaluate {
    android.sourceSets.all { sourceSet ->
        // Ensure Kt ain't used in production code
        if (!sourceSet.name.startsWith("test"))
            sourceSet.kotlin.setSrcDirs([])
    }
}`

Comment: did you resolve your problem, after I posted my answer below? The answer is to avoid taking an argument in your case, and use this instead of sourceSet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with the help of several people (Google + Gradle forums). Hopefully this can help others with other plugins.

The solution had three parts to solve,

1. Configure a plugin with the configure()
2. Access Groovy extensions
3. Iterate sourceSets.all in kotlin (which is obvious if your not unlucky enough to start with `sourceSets.all { sourceSet -> }`)

Here's the source

```
val Any.extensions get() = (this as org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware).extensions

android {
    sourceSets {
        // Variant 1 with individual setup
        named("main") {
            val a: com.android.build.api.dsl.AndroidSourceSet = this
            java.srcDir("src/sharedTest/java")
        }
    }
    // Variant 2 handling all at once
    sourceSets.all {
        val svgSourceSet = this.extensions["svg"] as SourceDirectorySet
        svgSourceSet.srcDir("src/${name}/svg")
    }
}
configure<com.trello.victor.VictorPluginExtension> {
    // Any assets defined in relative terms needs a base DPI specified
    svgDpi = 72
    // Do not generate these densities for SVG assets
    excludeDensities = listOf("ldpi", "xxxhdpi")
    // Set this to "true" if you want to generate Android vectors instead of PNGs
    generateVectorDrawables = false
}
```